# how could i manage to get answer in complex number from my code

Tags: c++

I have write this code to solve a quadratic formula but it doesn't work when the answer is complex(in iota form like 3i or √-3) i want to get answer in iota how could i manage it

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  float a,b,c,variable1,variable2,variable3,y,x,variable4;
  cout<<"Enter a:";
  cin>>a;
  cout<<"Enter b:";
  cin>>b;
  cout<<"Enter c:";
  cin>>c;
  variable1=-b;
  variable2=b*b;
  variable3=(4*a*c);
  variable4=(variable2-variable3);
  y=sqrtf(variable4);
  x=(variable1+y)/2;
  cout<<"x=" <<x <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Indent code correctly.

Comment: Borgleader how?

Comment: @UsmanQamar Step 1: Place cursor before a line that is improperly indented. Step 2: Press spacebar.

Comment: [`using namespace std;` is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2176813), never use it. Additionally `math.h` is a deprecated C-compatibility header - use `cmath` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The overload of `std::sqrt` that produces a complex result is declared in `<complex>` and takes a `std::complex<T>` as its argument, so to get a complex result, you need to start with a complex input, and include the correct header.

Here's a trivial example:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::complex<double> d{ -1, 0 };

    std::cout << std::sqrt(d);
}
```

Result:

```
(0,1)
```

Those represent the real and imaginary parts respectively, so this is `0+1i`, as we'd expect.

It may also be worth noting that starting with C++ 14, the standard library defines a user-defined literal for imaginary numbers, so you could initialize `d` like this:

```
using namespace std::literals;

auto d = -1.0 + 0i;
```

This produces the same result, but for people accustomed to writing a complex number as `a + bi`, it may look a little more familiar/comfortable. The one "trick" is that it's still doing type deduction, so to get a `complex<double>`, you need to use `-1.0` instead of `-1` (which I guess would try to deduce a `std::complex<int>`).